# Complex Case Statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a scenario where i have 4 columns - SUBBRAND, COLLECTIONS, PLCYCLE, COLORFAMILY and i have to assign priority to records:

1. If all 4 of them have valid values(not blank or not null) - Priority '1' ;
2. If any 3 of them have valid values(not blank or not null) - Priority '2' ;
3. If any 2 of them have valid values(not blank or not null) - Priority '3' ;
4. If any 1 of them have valid values(not blank or not null) - Priority '4' .

Is writing a case statement with all possible combinations the only way to get this done or is there any simple way of doing it ?

sample code:

```
CASE WHEN SUBBRAND IS NOT NULL AND COLLECTIONS IS NOT NULL 
     AND PLCYCLE IS NOT NULL AND COLORFAMILY  IS NOT NULL
     THEN 1 AS PRIORITY,
     WHEN SUBBRAND IS NOT NULL AND COLLECTIONS IS NOT NULL 
     AND PLCYCLE IS NOT NULL OR
     WHEN COLLECTIONS IS NOT NULL AND PLCYCLE IS NOT NULL 
     AND COLORFAMILY IS NOT NULL OR
     WHEN PLCYCLE IS NOT NULL AND COLORFAMILY IS NOT NULL
     AND WHEN SUBBRAND IS NOT NULL OR
     so on....
     THEN 2 AS PRIORITY
     and other conditions..
END PRIORITY
```

Thanks in Advance for your Help !

Comment: what if all are null? the trailing `OR` after each condition in your draft is invalid syntax. your approach is probably superior to any convoluted UNION-and-aggregation approach because a CASE on uncomputed columns is as cheap as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, empty string values are treated as `NULL`, so you only need to check for `NULL`.  
Use `NVL2` to produce `0` if `NULL` and `1` otherwise:

```
SELECT 
  5 - ( 
  NVL2(SUBBRAND, 1, 0) + 
  NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 1, 0) + 
  NVL2(PLCYCLE, 1, 0) + 
  NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 1, 0) 
  ) AS Priority
```

I guess there is no case of all 4 columns to be NULL.

Comment: Hello Everyone .. Thanks for taking your time to answer :) There is no valid business case where all four columns would be NULL; i mean, business is simply not considering that scenario as valid. And the priority values are fixed based on the number of columns that are not NULL. does this help ?

Comment: If there is a constraint set in the table for this case then there is no problem.

Comment: No, we do not have any constraint on the table for these columns. The fields (columns) are user maintained and they can choose to have values populated to these columns or leave them empty. If all 4 are empty, we have to disregard the corresponding records. The task is to check the combination of valid columns and assign their default priority; like all 4 have any values in them then the corresponding record gets priority assigned as 1 and any 3 then priority as 2 and so on..

Comment: *we have to disregard the corresponding records* this means that you take care of non valid rows, so it's fine, else just disregard if a priority comes out as 5.

Comment: yes, you are right. we would have to include a condition to handle the non valid rows but not assign any priority.

Comment: Is case statement the correct way to assign default priorities based on column combination or is there any other approach to get the result.

Comment: Case is the sql equivalent of the if statement of programming languages. it can be used in your case but as you mention in your question, this is complicated. Since there are alternatives, why use case?

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative method of achieving the result ? :)

Comment: Hi forpas, Thank you. the NVL2 query works for me. i have to include this logic as part of a bigger query with more flag checks/scenario's. Sorry, i couldn't reply earlier. Thanks again for you help :)

Comment: And, one more query, instead of the priorities being 1,2,3,4; how could i change the code to get priorities as 5,6,7,8 ? i.e. all 4 columns have valid values then 5, if 3 then 6 and so on..

Comment: Instead of `5 - ...` do `9 - ...`

Comment: Pls, Ignore the above comment, the query shared by johey and Gordon helps me with that requirement.                                                                                 
    SELECT SUBBRAND, COLLECTIONS, PLCYCLE, COLORFAMILY, 
                   5 /* highest priority */ + 
                     /* increase priority for each non-empty value */ 
                    + NVL2(SUBBRAND, 0, 1) + NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 0, 1) + 
                    NVL2(PLCYCLE, 0, 1) + NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 0, 1) 
                    AS PRIORITY
                    from T1;

Comment: Hi forpas.. yes, i tried that.. but with (9- or 5 +) code block i get Priority value as 9 when all 4 columns are empty; which is fine, but since i have a second scenario based on another flag check, i need to assign priorities as 9,10,11,12 again for the valid column combination.

Comment: to clarify my scenarios: i have a flag 'abc'; if abc = 1, then assign priorities as 5,6,7,8. if abc = 0, then assign priority as 9,10,11,12. :)

Comment: I'm just guessing now: (case abc when 1 then 9 when 0 then 13) - ( 
  NVL2(SUBBRAND, 1, 0) + 
  NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 1, 0) + 
  NVL2(PLCYCLE, 1, 0) + 
  NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 1, 0) 
  ) As priority

Comment: ahh ok.. i can split them into 2 code blocks and use them as part of 2 merge/insert statements into the final table. Now, is there a way to stop assigning priority for invalid rows.. like we get 9 or 13 when all 4 columns are empty. can we somehow avoid that and reject/not select those records ? i know i'm almost asking you to write the code for me. ;) but i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Include at the end this:`WHERE NVL2(SUBBRAND, 1, 0) +  NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 1, 0) +   NVL2(PLCYCLE, 1, 0) +  NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 1, 0) > 0`, so invalid rows will not be selected.

Comment: Hi @forpas.. Thank you so very much, buddy :) It all came together well. i'm posting the final code as an answer, as i cannot format code within a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first count the NULL values:

```
SELECT 1 /* highest priority */ + 
       /* increase priority for each non-empty value */ 
       + NVL2(SUBBRAND, 0, 1) + NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 0, 1) + NVL2(PLCYCLE, 0, 1) + NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 0, 1) 
  AS PRIORITY
...
```

As dlatikay noticed: you have to decide what if all values are empty. In the above solution the priority will become 5, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

`NVL2()` is handy if blank means no characters.  However, if "blank" allows spaces or other characters, you need `case` logic.  I would go for:

```
SELECT (1 +
        NVL2(TRIM(' ' FROM SUBBRAND), 0, 1) + 
        NVL2(TRIM(' ' FROM COLLECTIONS), 0, 1) + 
        NVL2(TRIM(' ' FROM PLCYCLE), 0, 1) + 
        NVL2(TRIM(' ' FROM COLORFAMILY), 0, 1) 
       ) AS Priority
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting the final code (sort of) that works for me.
Thanks to everyone for helping and a Big THANK YOU to forpas for all your help :))

```
SELECT U, V, W, X, Y, Z, SUBBRAND, COLLECTIONS, PLCYCLE, COLORFAMILY,  
  CASE 
       WHEN ABC = 1
       THEN (SELECT MAX (5 /* highest priority */ + 
             /* increase priority for each non-empty value */ 
             + NVL2(SUBBRAND, 0, 1) + NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 0, 1) + NVL2(PLCYCLE, 0, 1) + 
             NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 0, 1)) PRIORITY
               FROM T1) 
       WHEN ABC = 0
       THEN (SELECT MAX (9 /* highest priority */ + 
             /* increase priority for each non-empty value */ 
             + NVL2(SUBBRAND, 0, 1) + NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 0, 1) + NVL2(PLCYCLE, 0, 1) + 
             NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 0, 1)) PRIORITY
               FROM T1)
  END PRIORITY, ABC
FROM T1
WHERE NVL2(SUBBRAND, 1, 0) + NVL2(COLLECTIONS, 1, 0) + NVL2(PLCYCLE, 1, 0) + 
      NVL2(COLORFAMILY, 1, 0) > 0;
```

It would be very helpful if any performance tuning on this query can be suggested :D
Data Volume would be 100 M or more, apprx.